# Carrier Comfort 80 Ignition Proving Failure

Tags: furnace, carrier

It's getting chilly here in California and I'm having an issue with keeping my Carrier furnace fired up.

I have a Carrier Comfort 80 Deluxe (Model# 58DLX070-08). When reset, the blower runs and fires up the first then all three burners without issue. But after a while, I get an **Ignition Proving Failure** (code 34) then an **Ignition Lockout** (code 14) LED error.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix the issue? Thanks in advance and happy holidays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. If only the first **burner** that is connected to the **igniter** fires up but none of the other burners light, and then the furnace shuts down and retries, the culprit is most likely either,

1. Clogged flame spreader wings on the burners.
2. Low gas pressure set on the gas valve.

My issue was rust on the flame spreader wings on the burner assembly that prevented all the burners to fire up. That's what caused the **Ignition Proving Failure** (code 34) and subsequent **Ignition Lockout** (code 14) LED error. I had to remove the burner assembly and clean the **flame spreader wings** with a wire brush.

If you have the same issue where not all the burners fire up, try cleaning the flame spreader wings before replacing the **flame sensor**.

Here are some photos (click to enlarge):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

"Ignition proving" is engineer-speak for "verify that the gas is burning, not just flowing out into the room."

A diagram from a manual offered at manualslib.com shows the approximate location of the flame sensor. You could remove the sensor, clean it and its mounting location and hardware, and see what happens next.

Some furnaces use the hot surface igniter to sense the flame. These parts are usually very brittle and must be handled carefully to avoid cracking them or contaminating them with skin oils. It appears your furnace has a separate flame sensor. Although it might be less fragile than a hot surface igniter, I would suggest treating it with the same level of care.

The sensor could be cleaned by rubbing it with a somewhat gentle abrasive such as emery cloth or a "Scotch-brite" or similar red or green abrasive pad.

[image: parts location diagram]

Comment: Thanks, Greg. I replaced the Flame Sensor and now only the first burner (that's attached to the ignitor) fires up then the entire unit shuts down. I'm thinking the burner and/or manifold are clogged and needs a good cleaning. Will do so and check in here later.